# Grails - What is mixin and its significance in Grails Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, automated-tests

I am learning Grails Testing and in the first paragraph of the documentation it says that

**Grails 2.0.x and above deprecates these test harnesses in favour of mixins that can be applied to a range of different kinds of tests (JUnit 3, JUnit 4, Spock etc.) without subclassing**

I researched about it found that it is being used for special multiple inheritance in other language. I have also found the statement below:

**First, you should note that mixins only exist in multiple-inheritance languages. You can't do a mixin in Java or C#.**

Can somebody explain what is mixin and its significance in Grails Testing?

Comment: "First, you should note that mixins only exist in multiple-inheritance languages." - I am not sure where that quote came from and maybe there is some surrounding context which makes it ok but as written without that surround context that statement is false.  Mixins can be applied in single inheritance languages.  Groovy is an example.  In fact, one of the benefits is they allow you to deal with some of the limitations that single inheritance imposes.  The statement is peculiar by itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can somebody explain what is mixin and its significance in Grails
>   Testing?

Mixins contain behavior that can be "mixed in" to other classes.  Using inheritance in Groovy or Java one can only inherit from one super class.  Mixins allow behavior to be brought into a class from several other classes.

In early versions of Grails your unit test classes generally would inherit from `GroovyTestCase` or `GrailsUnitTestCase` in order for your test to inherit useful behavior.  A problem with that is if you wanted to use Spock or some other testing framework that comes along in the future, that was complicated because you would want to inherit behavior from the Spock test class but would also want to inherit behavior from the Grails test class.  With mixins we allow your unit tests to "inherit" all of the Grails test behavior via a mixin so we aren't tying up your 1 inheritance option and that leaves you to inherit from Spocks test class if you want.

There are a lot of ways that mixins improve the situation.  That is just one.